# How to update SQLCMD

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd

I am trying to run a file through sqlcmd using windows authentication and started running into errors. I was able to do some research and fig out that the version of SQLCMD I am using is old and does not support windows authentication well. I tried to download new versions of SQLCMD utility and install it but no luck. I am at a loss as to what the issue could be, any help would be greatly appreciated. Please see my SQL Server folder screenshot and folder 110 screenshot below.

[image: SQL Server Folder]

[image: 100 Folder]

Comment: You need to make sure `sqlcmd` is pointing at the newest version (or reference it directly, e.g. instead of just saying `sqlcmd` you say `C:\...\150\...\sqlcmd.exe` - see https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/232639/1186

Comment: Hi, yes its pointing to version 100. However, I have folders for 140 and 150 but both do not have Tools\Binn\ folders

Comment: Are the new versions in Add/Remove Programs? Are you sure a newer version installed correctly? Did you search your entire drive for all instances of `sqlcmd.exe`?

Answer (score 1):

SQLCMD is included in [Microsoft® Command Line Utilities 14.0 for SQL Server](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53591)